# Report interaction: set decimal delimiter to dot

Tags: reporting

Is it possible to set the decimal delimiter from a comma to a dot in report interactions?

"1,091" should become "1.091".

Answer (score 1):

All fields that are "number" fields in Salesforce is always displayed in the user's locale, including currency fields. To control the display, change your Locale in the Personal Settings area of Salesforce.